# Is there any option to save/insert records automatically on close of browser in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community

I am working on a lightning component that stores the session of the case records if he/she leaves the browser then automatically creates the records. But is there any way to handle event and creates the record.

[image]

Comment: leaves browser? means changes tabs etc?

Comment: means close the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the browser/tab is in the process of closing, all network activity is shut down. This means that you can't perform an action method once the tab is in shutdown process. Instead, you may want to use [lightning:unsavedChanges](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:unsavedChanges) so you can prevent closure while there are unsaved changes, or you can save automatically every so often, or possibly save the record locally in localStorage and allow loading the record later. Note this last option won't save to the server, but can at least prevent users from losing their work.

Comment: i am getting error
Failed to save test.cmp: No COMPONENT named markup://lightning:unsavedChanges found : [markup://c:test]: Source

Comment: @sarveshkumar Hmm, this might be a Spring 19 component. You might need to wait until the release to use it.

Comment: but I need. is there any way to do this

Comment: @sarveshkumar as far as I can tell, there's probably no other way to do so as you describe exactly. You may want to set a timer to save every 30 seconds or so, or come up with a different mechanism.

Comment: @sfdxfox is there any way to handle logout and sessionout session in component.

Comment: @sarveshkumar save beforehand. I use a sessionStorage or localStorage.

Comment: Can you please help me how to use sessionStorage and localStorage.